# Extract value from a HTML code with Karate UI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, karate, karate-call-single

This is the HTML code :  <input placeholder="Early" value="Oct 4, 2023" xpath="1">

My test wanna verify if the value of this field is equal  with the actual date time. I have The actual date time function maded but i dont know how can i extract this field .

This is the locator of the field :

```
"firstDateField" : "//input[contains(placeholder,Early)]/following-sibling::div"
```

I have tried with regex but it doenst work :

```
* def extractedValue = karate.replace(text, '.*Early.+value=\\"([A-Za-z]+ \\d{1,2}, \\d{4}).*', '$1')
* print 'Extracted value:', extractedValue
```